# jboss 9 java7 32bit run error - classnotfoundexception WSDLExtensionLoader

Tags: java, jboss, java-7

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        <subsystem name="webservices"/>
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cxf}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cxf}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cxf}</version>
    </dependency>
```

error - ClassNotFoundException: WSDLExtensionLoader
[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно тебе стоит добавить зависимость в pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
    <version>${version.cxf}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Скоро проверю, пока загрузка большая, неуспеваю чёт(

Answer (score 0):

`WSDLExtensionLoader` не найден, как вы можете заметить по логу ошибки. Думаю, что вы забыли какие-то зависимости в вашем **pom.xml**.